# My Win32 cmdline app doesn't start, just hangs, then can't be killed

Tags: c++, windows

I've built a little Win32 (command line) toy app using CMake. Something must have gone wrong though since whenever the .exe is started it just hangs.

It looks like it doesn't even get to `main()` since the first line in there is

```
std::cout << "blablabla" << std::endl;
```

and I don't even see that being printed.

When I put the Windows debugger on it, the debugger hangs while starting the app.

The most odd thing about it though is that once it hangs the process is basically un-killable and the .exe file remains un-accessible. I've tried the Task Manager, the MS Process Explorer and Unlocker 1.9.2 but neither tool is able to kill the process and un-lock the exe. The only thing that helps is to completely re-boot the machine.

I'd like to know whether there is a tool that allows me to see what exactly is going wrong when launching the .exe. Right now I don't have any insight into that since any attempts so far have just caused more hanging behavior.

Comment: There are too many reasons why this can happen to give a good diagnosis for your particular case. Try to narrow the environmental conditions more.

Comment: Please, if you really feel the strong urge to down-vote this, have the decency of leaving a comment explaining why. This is not a joke question and I'm happy to provide more detail if needed.

Comment: I left a comment, so what you're bothering about??

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ: The question is not about getting a diagnosis about what's going wrong but whether there exists a tool that allows me to get more insight.

Comment: Asking for tools is explicitly off-topic here, sorry.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ: Would you mind pointing me to the right place then?

Comment: Then this question is off topic. You would be better off asking for insight as to why you program is not working, but since you did not provide a reproducible example, that too, would be off topic.

Comment: Disable avast and try again.

Comment: @RafaelSpring Maybe [SE Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), not sure at all. Read their policies before asking.

Comment: @drescherjm: PERFECT, thanks! If you post it as an answer I'm more than happy to upvote and accept.

Comment: It's a duplicate. Although not easy to find. I voted to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Happy to accept the close as a duplicate. Thanks again.